# Restricted boltzmann machine - array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm doing a college assignment about RBM restricted Boltzmann machines. but this code error.I am confused how to get this code working. can anybody help me about this error?

```
def reconstruct(self, v):
    h = sigmoid(np.dot(v, self.W) + self.hbias)
    reconstructed_v = sigmoid(np.dot(h, self.W.T) + self.vbias)
    return reconstructed_v

def test_rbm(learning_rate=0.1, k=1, training_epochs=10):
data = datainput

rng = np.random.RandomState(123)

# construct RBM
rbm = RBM(input=data, n_visible=40, n_hidden=20, np_rng=rng)

# train
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    rbm.contrastive_divergence(lr=learning_rate, k=k)
    cost = rbm.get_reconstruction_cross_entropy()
    print ('Training epoch %d, cost is ' % epoch, cost, file = sys.stderr)

# test
v = datatarget
print (rbm.reconstruct(v))


if __name__ == "__main__":
test_rbm()

ValueError: shapes (1979,1) and (40,20) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 40 (dim 0)
```

at run time print(rbm.reconstruct(v)) error line in h = sigmoid(np.dot(v, self.W) + self.hbias)

Comment: Python is very sensitive about indentation. Perhaps `data = datainput` should be indented.

Comment: This code is no problem with indentation, code in my python not like this sir,  So there is no problem with indentation sir. my data input  = (1979,40) and data target = (1979,1). i will run for forecasting with RBM with visible layer = 40 and hidden layer = 20.